# Bundle up things in Codeigniter to use in multiple projects

Tags: codeigniter

I have a bunch of projects with codeigniter that all use a user controller. The controller does login, registration, user pages, etc. It also has a collection of views and a model. All of this stuff falls under /users/* in the url routes.

It would be great if all of this stuff that I reuse in each project was in one folder so it would be easy to do version management on it alone, and so it was easy to transport from project to project.

Is there a good way to do this with codeignighter?

Note: I use "user" as an example, but there are many things that I would like to bundle up and just drop into projects, such as forums, admin, etc.

Comment: have you considered looking into the HMVC modular setup? https://github.com/Bigwebmaster/codeigniter-modular-extensions-hmvc

this allows you to bundle "plugins" or "components" into any codeigniter environment.

each plugin/component works on the MVC principle..

not sure if this is what your looking for, but it is how i re-use alot of my code on other projects

Comment: have a look at **HMVC Bonfire** http://cibonfire.com/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If your code is reuseable (also for others) you could roll up a spark for it, see [sparks](http://getsparks.org).

If your code is reuseable for you alone you may have to use the HMVC modular setup as mentioned by @Dave and @dianuj or go with [git submodule](http://blogs.atlassian.com/2013/05/alternatives-to-git-submodule-git-subtree/) which I personally haven't had too much success with.